# CMake Error: Could not create named generator Android Gradle - Ninja

Tags: android, android-ndk

Gradle build window error:

[image]

Gradle Sync window error：

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Compatibility of `CMake` version might be an issue,
Old `NDK` (below 13b) is not compatible with the new `CMake`,
so, either update `NDK` or remove the new `CMake` (to force older CMake usage).

- Check your System Setting and version listed under SDK Tools

  > Go to Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK
- Incompatible 3.10.2
- **Compatible 3.6.4111459**

[image: IDE SDK Tools Configuration]